# Is there a known cron job or process in 16.04 that occurs every 30 or 60 minutes?

Tags: 16.04, kernel, cron

We have a system that needs millisecond accuracy and an operation that normally takes 23 milliseconds will suddenly take 129 ms every 30 minutes or 60 minutes. I was wondering in the standard 16.04.3 LTS desktop release generic  kernel whether anybody knows of a kernel process or cron job that happens to occur every hour or half hour. I don't see any jobs in the cron.hourly but we have processes in the cron.daily. I haven't configured the cron tab so it is very likely the default from the ubuntu desktop install. Any advise would be greatly appreciated as we desperately need a resolution to this.

```
$ ls /etc/cron.*
/etc/cron.d:
anacron  popularity-contest

/etc/cron.daily:
0anacron  apt-compat    cracklib-runtime  logrotate  mlocate  popularity-contest      upstart
apport    bsdmainutils  dpkg              man-db     passwd   update-notifier-common

/etc/cron.hourly:

/etc/cron.monthly:
0anacron

/etc/cron.weekly:
0anacron  fstrim  man-db  update-notifier-common
```

Note: chef is not installed on our system

Comment: Have you examined the output of `journalctl -u cron.service`?

Comment: I would also monitor `top` to try to catch a CPU consuming process in the act.

Comment: @steeldriver I haven't. Is that something I need to configure or is it on by default? If its already on do you know where it outputs to?

Comment: `journalctl` is a command that you run to examine the system logs (on systems that use `systemd`) - it outputs to the terminal, and in this case should give you a time-stamped list of cron jobs

Comment: Also do not forget about systemd timers - list them with `systemctl list-units --type timer`.

Comment: Are you running a RTOS (real time operating system)?

Answer (score 3):

`cron` is only one of the running daemons that consume CPU cycles and system resources:

```
$ ps -eo 'tty,pid,comm' | grep ^? | grep cron
?          841 cron
?          896 cron
```

For a complete list of all 264 on my system I use:

```
ps -eo 'tty,pid,comm' | grep ^?
```

So which deamon runs every 30 minutes? The first google hit is the `chef` deamon (not a cooking thing): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905278/chef-daemon-running-every-30-minutes

If it's not documented you would have to check every single daemon's source code to see how often it run.

Comment: Chef isn't a cooking thing, it's a service orchestration thing.

Comment: Would anyone know if chef is installed by default with 16.04 desktop or how I tell if it's is installed?

Comment: @RobotHumans I added the word `not` in front of `cooking` :). Thanks!

Comment: @simgineer You can type `chef` in the command line. Two lines might appear, 1: `The program 'chef' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:` and 2: `sudo apt install filters`

Comment: Okay looks like chef isn't installed on our systems.

Comment: @simgineer, the spirit of the google reference is it might tell you which daemons wake up every 30 minutes. `chef` is simply the first one on the list. Google doesn't look at your machine to see daemons running and use that in the search engine, at least it's not that advanced yet. On my own machine I have `find` running on the entire disk every 10 minutes, `locate` command's `updatedb` running every 15 minutes and Laptop Display Brightness gradual adjustment running every minute. Of the 264 daemon's you might have running you'll have to research how often they wake up.